# Accessing Dell Utility/Recovery Partition

Tags: windows-xp, boot, dell-inspiron

I'm having trouble accessing the Dell Utility/Recovery Partition.

I've seen all kinds of articles online that tell me to press some magic key combo when I see the Dell splash screen, but I never see the Dell splash screen.  Just the initial boot screen and then straight to the Windows XP screen.

I know the Dell partition is there because I saw it when I attempted to reinstall windows.

What is the easiest way for me to boot from the Dell Partition so I can re-image the machine back to factory defaults?

Comment: What model is your Dell?

Comment: @Force Flow: Inspiron 1501 (Laptop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found the answer to my question here:

http://tp0x45.blogspot.com/2008/04/solved-system-restore-dsr-fix-dell.html

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen is the Dell logo with a loading bar. If it's been disabled, you'll see a listing of your system specs (RAM, CPU, drives, etc).

During that time, press Ctrl+F11

If it doesn't appear, you might not have the PC Restore feature and will have to use the CDs that came with your laptop.

[edit]: 
Your laptop's manual [can be found here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBQQxQEwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fviewer%3Fa%3Dv%26q%3Dcache%3AOSPhGYpA2aUJ%3Asupport.dell.com%2Fsupport%2Fedocs%2Fsystems%2Fins1501%2Fen%2Fom_en%2Fpdf%2FHN926A00.pdf%2Brecovery%2Bdell%2B1501%2Bsite%3Adell.com%26hl%3Den%26gl%3Dus%26pid%3Dbl%26srcid%3DADGEESjDcAKpvpsUgB1bNGQIRvUUiP7JUjzcevByjqMFT42IW1id4VsgNVcZFL904PXx2Jawya8vG5eXtSGXgXr2GQWKIBRINmjYJmOt6Qm1au03Uve8689gI6FdzULC89zcDGg5u0Pp%26sig%3DAHIEtbRs2vxj0iN_geomCJC9ZH9aN4kwRQ&rct=j&q=recovery%20dell%201501%20site%3Adell.com&ei=B0KyTPBgwd-WB8758OYP&usg=AFQjCNGcmWBKhtr-ktnm38YwRLePlEYCUA&cad=rja). Jump to page 84.

Comment: After some further investigation, the steps outlined above were not working because the Master Boot Record had changed and did not know about the Dell Recovery Partition.  I had to burn a CD and boot from it in order to repair the partition and gain access to the Dell Recovery software.